# Django form save: Object is None, but form is valid

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-forms

I expect the [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15184000/django-overriden-form-save-method-returns-none) is related to the problem I have, but it is unfortunately not the same and I have not been able to use it to solve the problem. I also tried following the [method here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45221097/add-data-to-django-form-before-it-is-saved), which also is not proving successful in solving this particular issue.

**Here is the issue**: I am trying to use a simple form to create a new object. Some of the info comes from the user, some of the info comes from the system. When I process the POST request, using simple print statements I can see that the form is valid, and that it has the right data. But then when I go to save it tells me the object is None so it's not saving anything.

Below follows:

- views.py
- forms.py
- models.py
- template.html

What am I missing? Thank you!

---

**views.py**

```
def add_set_to_active_workout(request):
    workout = get_active_workout()
    if request.method == "POST":
        form = SetForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            print(f"Cleaned data is: {form.cleaned_data}") # This prints what I'd expect, namely, the user submitted data. 
            set = form.save(commit=False)
            set.workout = workout
            print(f"Set is {set}") # This prints: Set is Set object (None)
            set.save()
            print("set saved")
            return HttpResponseRedirect(reverse("log:active_workout"))
        else:
            return render(request, "log/active_workout.html", {
                "set_form": form,
                'workout': workout
            })
    else:
        return render(request, "log/active_workout.html", {
            "set_form": SetForm(), 'workout': workout,
        })
```

**The print statement `print(f"Set is {set}") Set is Set object (none)`. This is the problem to solve.** Here are the exact print statements:

`Cleaned data is: {'exercise': <Exercise: Deadlift>, 'actual_weight': 225.0, 'actual_reps': 12, 'actual_difficulty': 'easy'}`

`Set is Set object (None)`

`set saved`

forms.py

```
class SetForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Set
        fields = ['exercise', 'actual_weight', 'actual_reps', 'actual_difficulty']
```

models.py

```
class Set(models.Model):
    exercise = models.ForeignKey(Exercise, related_name="sets", on_delete=models.SET("Exercise Deleted!"))
    workout = models.ForeignKey(Workout, related_name="sets", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    actual_reps = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    actual_weight = models.FloatField()

    difficulty_options = (
        ("easy", "easy"),
        ("medium", "medium"),
        ("hard", "hard")
    )
    actual_difficulty = models.CharField(choices=difficulty_options, max_length=6)

    set_complete = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

template.html

```
<h2>Add a Set:</h2>
<form action="{% url 'log:add_set_to_active_workout' %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ set_form.as_p }}
    <input type="submit" value="Save Set" class="btn btn-secondary">
</form>
```

Comment: What exactly is printed out?

Comment: @ewokx Thank you for your help. The print statements in console are: <br>
```Cleaned data is: {'exercise': <Exercise: Deadlift>, 'actual_weight': 225.0, 'actual_reps': 12, 'actual_difficulty': 'easy'}
Set is Set object (None)
Set saved```
Added to answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to print the representation of a new object before saving it:

```
print(f"Set is {set}") # This prints: Set is Set object (None)
set.save()
```

```
set.save()
print(f"Set is {set}")
```

I would also advise not to use set as variable name as it is a built in [type](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Comment: This was it, thank you! I had a second error in my html template so it wasn't pulling from the database: the print statement showed nothing, and template showed nothing, so I assumed the problem was I wasn't saving. When I checked Django admin though all the data was there. This answer was what I needed to fix everything. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

When you call `print(object_name)` it calls the `__str__` method inside the object. The [default implementation](https://github.com/django/django/blob/45ecd9acca9b36093e274f47b6877a5f79108d9e/django/db/models/base.py#L590) of the models looks like this (unless you override it):

```
def __str__(self):
    return "%s object (%s)" % (self.__class__.__name__, self.pk)
```

As you have used `commit=False` during saving the form, it did not store the object in database, hence the `pk` is None. That is why when you print, you get

```
Set object (None)
^^^^^^^^^^ ^^^^^
class name   pk
```

But after you save it using `set.save()` then print it, it should return `Set object (1)`.

***FYI: You should use a different variable name other than `set`, because it represents [`set` data type](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets) in Python.***